# Is there a way to have fixtures that are specific to a certain tests and not all in the given namespace?

Tags: clojure, midje, clojure.test

just like `midje` lets us wrap `facts` in a `with-state-changes` form to specify what should run specifically before, around or after them or the content, how does one accomplish the same with clojure.test

Answer (score 2):

fixtures in clojure.test are functions that take a function as an argument, do some setup, call the function, then do some cleanup.

tests (as created with deftest) are functions that take no arguments and run the appropriate tests.

So to apply a fixture to a test you just wrap that test in the fixture

```
user> (require '[clojure.test :refer [deftest is testing]])
nil
```

a function to test:

```
user> (def add +)
#'user/add
```

a test for it:

```
user> (deftest foo (is (= (add 2 2) 5)))
#'user/foo
```

create a fixture that changes math so the test can pass:

```
user> (defn new-math-fixture [f]
        (println "setup new math")
        (with-redefs [add (constantly 5)]
          (f))
        (println "cleanup new math"))
#'user/new-math-fixture
```

without the fixture the test fails:

```
user> (foo)

FAIL in (foo) (form-init5509471465153166515.clj:574)
expected: (= (add 2 2) 5)
  actual: (not (= 4 5))
nil
```

and if we change math our test is fine:

```
user> (testing "new math"
        (new-math-fixture foo))
setup new math
cleanup new math
nil
user> (testing "new math"
        (deftest new-math-tests
          (new-math-fixture foo)))
#'user/new-math-tests
user> (new-math-tests)
setup new math
cleanup new math
nil
```

Comment: is there a way to apply fixtures on a specific group of tests rather than all of them within the namespace.

Comment: Replace `foo` with `#(test1 test2 test3)` in the above example.